# How to match correct group name(.NET C# Regex)

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get some information form a string, and I want to use group name to get information, but I can't do a correct result.

My Code

```cs
Regex _Regex = new Regex(@"\AFilePath: (?<FilePath>.+), ContentType: (?<ContentType>.+)[, PrinterName: ]? (?<PrinterName>.+),DownloadFileName: (?<DownloadFileName>.+)\z");
    string _String = @"FilePath: C:\Download\TEST.docx, ContentType: WORD, PrinterName: RICOH Aficio MP C4501 PCL 6, DownloadFileName: TEST.docx";
    Match _Match = _Regex.Match(_String);
    if (_Match.Success == true)
{
  string FileNme = _Match.Groups["FilePath"].Value;
  string ContentType = _Match.Groups["ContentType"].Value;
  string PrinterName = _Match.Groups["PrinterName"].Value;
  string DownloadFileName = _Match.Groups["DownloadFileName"].Value;
}
```

I expect I can get FileNme, CreateTime, PrinterName, DownloadFileName information by the Regex, like this:

```
FileNme = "C:\Download\TEST.docx"
ContentType = "WORD"
PrinterName = "RICOH Aficio MP C4501 PCL 6"
DownloadFileName = "TEST.docx"
```

But actually, result with this regex is like this

```
FileNme = "C:\Download\TEST.docx"
ContentType = "WORD, PrinterName:  RICOH Aficio MP C4501 PCL"
PrinterName = "6"
DownloadFileName = "TEST.docx"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\AFilePath:\s*(?<FilePath>.*?),\s*ContentType:\s*(?<ContentType>.*?),\s*PrinterName:\s*(?<PrinterName>.*?),\s*DownloadFileName:\s*(?<DownloadFileName>.+)\z
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CAFilePath%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3CFilePath%3E.*%3F%29%2C%5Cs*ContentType%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3CContentType%3E.*%3F%29%2C%5Cs*PrinterName%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3CPrinterName%3E.*%3F%29%2C%5Cs*DownloadFileName%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3CDownloadFileName%3E.%2B%29%5Cz&i=FilePath%3A%20C%3A%5CDownload%5CTEST.docx%2C%20ContentType%3A%20WORD%2C%20PrinterName%3A%20RICOH%20Aficio%20MP%20C4501%20PCL%206%2C%20DownloadFileName%3A%20TEST.docx)

[image]

Basically, all parts of the regex represent some hardcoded string (like `FilePath:`), then 0+ whitespaces (matched with `\s*`) and then a named capturing group (like `(?<FilePath>.*?)`) that capture any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few times as possible (instead of the last one where the greedy dot pattern is required, `.+` or `.*`).

If the printer name part can be missing you need to enclose `,\s*PrinterName:\s*(?<PrinterName>.*?)` with `(?:...)?`, i.e. `(?:,\s*PrinterName:\s*(?<PrinterName>.*?))?`.